# Can't render react-bootstrap modal on server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to know why I am unable to render react-bootstrap's modal on the server.

When I do the following on the server, I get `<!-- react-empty: 1 -->`:

```
renderToString(
  <Modal>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      some text
    </Modal.Header>

    <Modal.Body>
      some text
    </Modal.Body>
  </Modal>
));
```

It seems that `<Modal>` does not render anything but rather attaches a modal to the DOM using JavaScript. But I am not too sure how it works. Any suggestions on how to render a react-bootstrap's modal on server?

*I also saw [this issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/717) but it seems not directly related.*

Version: react-bootstrap 0.29.4, react 15.1.0, react-dom 15.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to render modal on the server side.

Got this answer from react-bootstrap member:

> Rendering of shown overlays on the server is intentionally not supported.

See [this issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1971#issuecomment-227337729).

Comment: It's because of the underlying Portal concept that the Modal and Overlay paradigm is using. Ryan Florence gave a great description of the concept at React Conf https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5e7kWSHWTg#t=15m17s. This concept does not play well in the server side rendering environment due to the lack of a DOM to interact with.